# Injecting Singleton Into Guice AOP Method Interceptor

Tags: java, singleton, aop, guice

I have a method interceptor that I inject a class X that is annotated with @Singleton. I noticed that unless I additionally bind that class X as an EagerSingleton Guice creates two instances of that Singleton class. One that is used by my method interceptor and one that is used by all other classes whose constructors depend on that class X. I've checked this behavior by looking at the hashcodes of each class that is generated, and I'm wondering why adding EagerSingleton() is necessary? My hunch is that requesting injection of a method interceptor causes the injectors creation to bypass the lazy implementation of Singletons. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stakoverflow! Please see how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the module where you are injecting and binding your interceptor?